# How to redirect sub.domain.com to www.domain.com/dir/page.html?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, bind, 301-redirect

I have a old dataserver(**data.example.com**) which was replaced by a NAS and NAS shares are now mounted on a webserver (**[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)**).

So now the oldserver is removed and **i have made a "CNAME" on our DNS to point to our webserver** and since our paths are the same on old dataserver and webserver, the pages are being linked properly ie. "data.example.com/datafolder1 redirects to "www.example.com/datafolder1" as it should.

**But how can i make it so that data.example.com redirects to [www.example.com/dir/page.html](http://www.example.com/dir/page.html) that has information of the fact that the oldserver has been removed and links to the actual data folders?**

Here are the configs in question:

Bind9: example.hosts

```
data.example.com.         IN      CNAME   www.example.com.
```

Apache: [www.example.com.conf](http://www.example.com.conf)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName data.example.com
  
  # 301 --- data.example.com => www.example.com/Info/dataserver.html
  RewriteRule ^data\.example\.com$ /www.example.com/Info/dataserver.html? [L,R=301]

  LogLevel warn rewrite:trace3
  ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/error-data.example.com.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-data.example.com.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost serverip:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

  # Redirecting all http > https
  Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/

  LogLevel error rewrite:trace3
  ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/error-example.com.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-example.com.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/www.example.com/htdocs/

  SSLEngine on
  etc........
```

With current configuration data.example.com is redirecting to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) homepage not the the **[www.example.com/dir/page.html](http://www.example.com/dir/page.html)** like i would like it to.

Comment: Why not make sub-dir links/redirs via HTML not from the DNS ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The data.example.com is gone forever, i cant make redirect links there that would redirect to www.example.com if thats what you meant.

Comment: If the sub-domain is gone, what is the logic of the redirect ? If it needs to do/open something, why delete it in the 1st place ?

Comment: It was deleted because it was an ancient windows server that we replaced with new NAS and we need redirect to preserve old urls that users and bots still use. That part works, like i said old.domain.com/folder links to domain.com/folder like it should, only problem is how to redirect old.domain.com to domain.com/folder/file.html that notifies users of the change and so they can slowly update links perhaps, or something along those lines.

Comment: Would seem to be a terminology confusion... the server that `data.example.com` originally pointed to is "gone forever". The subdomain `data.example.com` is obviously not "gone" (which @Overmind would seem to be referring to), since you've created a CNAME record, pointing it to your server and your server is accepting requests to `data.example.com`. (Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to create a redirect.)

Comment: "With current configuration `data.example.com` is redirecting to `www.example.com` homepage" - where is this redirect currently implemented?

Comment: Drop an index.html on your old.domain.com which has internal URL to /folder/file. As I said initially, it's easy to do it like that.

Comment: @MrWhite Its the DNS cname that points `data.example.com > www.domain.com` currently, there is no apache config for that redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   ServerName data.example.com
>   
>   # 301 --- data.example.com => www.example.com/Info/dataserver.html
>   RewriteRule ^data\.example\.com$ /www.example.com/Info/dataserver.html? [L,R=301]
> ```

Presumably this *redirect* is your "attempt" at redirecting `http://data.example.com/` to `http://www.example.com/dir/page.html` - as per your question text (although this should presumably be `https://`).

What this redirect actually does is redirect `http://data.example.com/data.example.com` to `http://data.example.com/www.example.com/Info/dataserver.html` - probably not your intention.

To redirect `http://data.example.com/` (document root only) to `https://www.example.com/dir/page.html` you should change the above `RewriteRule` to the following (no need for mod_rewrite here):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ https://www.example.com/dir/page.html
```

To redirect `http://data.example.com/<anything>` then change the above to read:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^ https://www.example.com/dir/page.html
```

You'll need to restart your webserver for the change to take effect.

Comment: Hmm.. made the modification and now  **http ://data.example.com/** redirects to /var/www/html/index.html and **https ://data.example.com/** redirects to www.example.com. Must be something else im missing then...

Comment: Ok, it works now, **data.example.com redirects to www.example.com/dir/page.html**, but the other redirects stopped working, ie. data.example.com/folder1 returns 404, when it was previously returning www.example.com/folder1

Comment: Alright, i just had to make **Redirect 301 /foldername https://www.example.com/foldername** redirects to each folder to the them all working, luckily there were that many folders.

Comment: Glad you got it working... **#1** "now `http://data.example.com/` redirects to `/var/www/html/index.html` and `https://data.example.com/1` redirects to `www.example.com`" - that couldn't have been caused by the above directive. For `https://` to have redirected then the directive must have been put in a different vHost? **#2** "but the other redirects stopped working" - the directive above that redirects "just the document root" should not have affected any other redirects. What other redirects were implemented? There's nothing relevant in what you posted above.

Comment: **#3** "had to make `Redirect 301 /foldername https://www.example.com/foldername`" - how was it redirecting before? You would need something like that, otherwise, there will be no "auto" redirect. A CNAME record is not a "redirect". There are no related redirects in what you posted above?

Comment: As i understand it `data.example.com. IN CNAME www.example.com.` in DNS will redirect `data.example.com/folder1 to www.example.com/folder1`. What i linked is the complete virtualhost file, theres only SSL and <Directory..> configurations that is missing from it. The only other change i made was to `www.example.com` vhost where i changed`<VirtualHost ip_add:80> ` to `<VirtualHost *:80>.

Comment: No, a CNAME record is not a "redirect". It does not change the URL in the addr bar - the user is not "redirected". A CNAME record (as with anything DNS) simply points the request to an IP address (in this case, the IP address that `www.example.com` points to).

Comment: A "redirect", on the other hand, is an "HTTP external **redirect**". You request URL "A", the server (not DNS) responds with a 3xx redirect response identifying URL "B" - the URL to be redirected to. The user-agent then makes an entirely separate (second) request to the URL identified in the redirect response (B). This is what the `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` (and `RewriteRule`) directives do - they send a 301 redirect response identifying the URL (B) that the user-agent should request. A CNAME record alone results in 1 HTTP request. A "redirect" is two separate requests.